# Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined after adding form button

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code that I have written to copy data from multiple sheets into a new master sheet and it was working fine until I made a little changes to my code to add a form button to import data now when I click the button I get the error

> Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined

can anyone help me ? here is the code for the `btnImport` button in the `ImportForm`:

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click()

  Dim bookList As Workbook
  Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object

  Dim folderpath As String

  folderpath = Range("I5").Value

  If Range("I5").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select the folder which contains the reports.", vbInformation, "Cannot Import."
    Range("I2").Select
  ElseIf FileFolderExists(folderpath) = False Then
  MsgBox "Selected Folder Does Not Exist.", vbInformation, "Cannot Import."
    Range("I5").Select
  ElseIf Dir(folderpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Selected Folder Not Found.", vbInformation, "Invalid Folder Name."
    Range("I5").Select

  Else
    Me.lblWait.Visible = True
    Me.btnCancel.Visible = False
    Me.btnImport.Visible = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Collecting Data, Please Wait..."
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("folderpath")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    On Error Resume Next

    'Change B3:H to the range your working on and also B in B65536 to any column required.
     bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("B3:H350" & bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

  'Below only change "B" column name to your required column name
  Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  bookList.Close
  Next

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: which line errors out?

Comment: @user3598756 while the VBA goes in debugging it highlights this line: `Private Sub btnImport_Click()`

Comment: Do you have a button named `btnImport`?

Comment: @KyloRen Yes I have it is in the `ImportForm`

Comment: @Hazmat:"while the VBA goes in debugging it highlights this line: Private Sub btnImport_Click()": This line is highlighted yellow. What is highlighted blue?

Comment: @AxelRichter I am new to VBA when I run the project I only get yellow over that mentioned line, I can't see any blue highlight :(

Comment: @KyloRen One point to add that when I was using a direct link like this: `Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test\")` it was working fine now that I add a form and added buttons for it, it gives me the mentioned error. the path code is now like this: `Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("folderpath")` :(

Comment: @AxelRichter, `What is highlighted blue` what program are you using?

Comment: @Hazmat ,Is there a button with the same name on the form? Or are you trying to call this button from the newly created form?

Comment: @KyloRen There was a button not on the form but on the excel sheet that used to bring the `importForm` that further had two button 1. `btnImport` 2. `btnCancel` since this error occured I changed the main sheet button from import to `btnMainImport` but still I get the error!!!

Comment: Just want to point out that `btnMainImport` is not the same as the button name in your function, `btnImport`

Comment: No I have renamed them both of them are different now! @KyloRen Should I post a snapshot of it ?

Comment: No need. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: @KyloRen I do, but just right now I commented the `IF and IF-Else` section to go a little bit deeper and now I get the yellow highlight over the path link here: `Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("folderpath")` !!! is there anything wrong here ?

Comment: What is the value in `Range("I5").Value`, this is the folder path correct?

Comment: @KyloRen Yes in excelsheet in `I5` there is the path: `C:\Users\hazmat\Desktop\test

Comment: @KyloRen but I don't know why compiler still gives this: `Run-time error '76': Path not found` :(

Comment: @KyloRen thank you found it myself by removing the `" "` double quotations from `folderpath` in this line: `Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("folderpath")` like this: `Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(folderpath)` :)

Comment: @Hazmat,  it could just be a problem with the path in your code or a filename with illegal characters in it, check the path, also take out the quotes

Comment: @KyloRen thanks a ton from your help, already found it :)

Comment: Where is FileFolderExists?  Mine wont' compile because this doesn't exist.

Comment: @KyloRen sure because it will help others as well just don't forget to upvote my question too and if possible star it as well ;)

Comment: @KerryWhite the path is in User side in the excel sheet at column i row 5 (I5)

Comment: @KyloRen thanks again and already marked as answer also just upvoted it

Comment: Thankyou, have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line please remove the quotation marks,

```
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("folderpath")
```

This will cause the error due to it being a variable.

It should be like this,

```
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(folderpath)
```